# malloc convert memory for struct

Tags: c, malloc

What is the right way to malloc memory ? And what is the difference between them ?

```
void parse_cookies(const char *cookie, cookie_bank **my_cookie, int *cookies_num)
{
   *my_cookie = malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank) * 1);
   *my_cookie = (cookie_bank *)malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank) * 1);
   my_cookie = (cookie_bank **)malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank) * 1); 
   ///
}
```

I'm trying to malloc array of cookie_bank structs function.

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to say what's right. Remove the casts, though, those are definitely not right (i.e. they're unnecessary).

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that you want the function to allocate memory for an array and passing the result via a pointer parameter. So, you want to write `T * x = malloc(...)`, and assign the result to a pointer argument, `*y = x`:

```
cookie_bank * myarray;
parse_cookies(..., &myarray, ...);
/* now have myarray[0], myarray[1], ... */
```

So the correct invocation should be, all rolled into one line,

```
parse_cookies(..., cookie_bank ** y, ...)
{
  *y = malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank) * NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second example is the most correct. You don't need the *1 obviously.

```
*my_cookie = (cookie_bank *)malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank) * 1);
```

Your first example is also correct, although some compilers/flags will cause a complaint about the implicit cast from void*:

```
*my_cookie = malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank) * 1);
```

It you want to allocate more than one entry you'd generally use calloc() because it zeros the memory too:

```
*my_cookie = (cookie_bank*)calloc(sizeof(cookie_bank), 1);
```

your third example is just wrong:

```
my_cookie = (cookie_bank **)malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank) * 1);
```

This will overwrite the local my_cookie pointer, and the memory will be lost on function return.

Comment: Yeah that third one is just going to hurt...Second line is what you should be doing.

Comment: In particular, a C++ compiler will complain about the implicit cast from `void`.  That's allowed in C but not in C++.

Comment: @Wyzard: You shouldn't be using malloc in C++ anyway.

Comment: No, but some people compile their C code with a C++ compiler, for whatever reason.  Or they "write C" but they're really writing C++ and just not using most of the language's features.

Comment: This answer is bad advice, for reasons I have heard from comp.lang.c: first, the cast will hide a compiler warning if you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` (the malloc function gets implicitly defined when it's called, and will return int, a non-pointer type).  Second, it is unstable: if you decide to change the type of my_cookie later, you have to change it both in its declaration and in the malloc call.  If you forget the latter, you potentially get a very odd bug.  Malloc returns void* precisely because it is universally implicitly convertible to any other pointer type.

Comment: @Wyzard: In that case, the compiler warning would seem to be telling them something they ought to know.  Namely, that they are using the wrong language.

Comment: @Wyzard there are reasons to use malloc()/free() in C++ code. Just because the language provides new/delete doesn't mean they're useful in every instance. They are os-specific system calls, not language specific.

Comment: @Ryan Reich: The converse is also true - if you changed the function prototype but didn't alter the sizeof() call you would see similar strange results. Having, or not, the cast doesn't change the risk associated with this line of code.

Comment: @Adam: I didn't even notice that the sizeof() was given incorrectly.  Since sizeof takes an expression, whether or not it is meaningful, one should just write `sizeof *my_cookie`.  Then only the variable name is used, and its type is inferred by the compiler from its declaration, as it should be.

Comment: @Ryan Reich: I usually avoid giving stylistic remarks - both of the OP's first two snippets are syntactically correct. There is nothing "given incorrectly" in either of them.

Comment: @Adam: Let me say then that the sizeof() expression is *fragile*, or prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

I just would like to recommend you to read some C textbook.  It seems to me that you do not have clear understanding on how pointers work in C language.

Anyway, here is some example to allocate memory with malloc.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void parse_cookies(const char *cookie, cookie_bank **my_cookie, int *cookies_num)
{
    if (cookies_num == NULL || *cookies_num == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (my_cookie == NULL) {
        my_cookie = (cookie_bank**)malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank*) * *cookies_num);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < *cookies_num; i++) {
        *my_cookie = (cookie_bank*)malloc(sizeof(cookie_bank));
        my_cookie++;
    }
}
```

Of course, this example does not cover any error handling.  Basically, my_cookie is pointer to pointer which means my_cookie is just pointer to point memory location where it holds array of pointers.  The first malloc allocate the memory using size of pointer and requested number of cookie structure.  Then second malloc actually allocate memory for each structure.

The problem of this function is that it can easily cause memory leak unless using this very carefully.

Anyway, it is important to understand how C pointer works.